# what is the correct way to format a connection string for azure analysis services using Microsoft.AnalysisServices.NetCore

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-analysis-services

Creating a function app to refresh a data model in azure analysis services based on a timer trigger. Using Microsoft.AnalysisServices.NetCore package.

What is the correct way to format the connection string? have i done this correctly?

```
// analysis services details
string serverName = "myserver";
string databaseName = "mydb";
string userId = "userId";
string password = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PWD");

//connection string
var connectionString = $"Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source=asazure://uksouth.asazure.windows.net/{serverName};Initial Catalog={databaseName};User ID={userId};Password={password};Persist Security Info=True;Impersonation Level=Impersonate";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The way which you have set the Connection String is correct but the `Data Source` has to be only the server name.

[image]

It has to be

```cs
var connectionString = $"Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source={serverName};Initial Catalog={databaseName};User ID={userId};Password={password};Persist Security Info=True;Impersonation Level=Impersonate;";
```

- Even you can check the same in [MSDOC Connection string properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/connection-string-properties-analysis-services?view=asallproducts-allversions#connection-properties)

Refer blogs by [Sanjay Bhagia](https://medium.com/@bhagiasanjay/accessing-azure-analysis-services-models-using-net-core-a80fa315af70#:%7E:text=The%20correct%20Connection%20String%20format%20is%3A%20%E2%80%9C%20Provider%3DMSOLAP%3BData,Catalog%3D%3Cmodelname%3E%3BUser%20ID%3D%3BPassword%3D%3Caccess%20token%20here%3E%3BPersist%20Security%20Info%3DTrue%3BImpersonation%20Level%3DImpersonate%20%E2%80%9C) and [James Broome](https://endjin.com/blog/2020/02/azure-analysis-services-how-to-open-a-connection-from-net) even it explains the same.

I have tried to connect it from my Application.

[image]

- You can add `AdomdConnection` using `Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient`;

My `.csproj` file:

```cs
<PackageReference Include="Unofficial.Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClientNetCore" Version="15.3.1.2" />
```

- Make sure to add the user in the [Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/tutorials/analysis-services-tutorial-roles#add-a-user-account-to-the-server-administrator-role) section.

Comment: would this also work if i have a sql user for example in my code i have sql_user as id and the password for it. do i need to add this user as a admin to analysis services as well?

Comment: I haven't check that with sql user ..Iam not sure about it.Can you check it once.